# Jest Tests Failing on Github Actions

Tags: node.js, github, jestjs, github-actions

I have a Repo that i'm working on right now that uses clean architecture with TDD. When i run the tests locally on my machine everything is ok. but when i'm trying to use with Github Actions to run on every commit and PR i'm getting a lot of errors. I also have husky and lint-staged.

[image]
[image]

My jest configs:

```js
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],
  collectCoverageFrom: ['<rootDir>/src/**/*.ts', '!<rootDir>/src/main/**'],
  coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  transform: {
    '.+\\.ts$': 'ts-jest'
  },
  preset: '@shelf/jest-mongodb',
}
```

```js
// jest-unit.config.js
const config = require('./jest.config')

config.testMatch = ['**/*.spec.ts']
module.exports = config
```

```js
// jest-integration.config.js
const config = require('./jest.config')

config.testMatch = ['**/*.test.ts']
module.exports = config
```

```js
// jest-mongodb.config.js
module.exports = {
  mongodbMemoryServerOptions: {
    instance: {
      dbName: 'jest'
    },
    binary: {
      version: '4.0.3',
      skipMD5: true
    },
    autoStart: false
  }
}
```

My Github Action

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2-beta
        with:
          node-version: '12'
          check-latest: true

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: yarn

      - name: Test
        run: yarn test:ci --verbose
```

and my package.json scripts

```
    "start": "node dist/main/server.js",
    "build": "rimraf dist && tsc",
    "build:watch": "tsc -w",
    "debug": "nodemon -L --watch ./dist --inspect=0.0.0.0:9222 --nolazy ./dist/main/server.js",
    "dev": "docker-compose",
    "up": "yarn build && yarn dev up",
    "down": "yarn dev down",
    "lint": "eslint 'src/**' --quiet",
    "lint:fix": "eslint 'src/**' --quiet --fix",
    "test": "jest --passWithNoTests --silent --noStackTrace --runInBand",
    "test:verbose": "jest --passWithNoTests --runInBand --watch",
    "test:unit": "yarn test --watch -c ./jest-unit.config.js",
    "test:integration": "yarn test --watch -c ./jest-integration.config.js",
    "test:staged": "yarn test --findRelatedTests",
    "test:ci": "yarn test --coverage"
```

Answer (score 4):

try add --maxWorkers=2 to your jest command. This will prevent jest from accidentally spawning too many workers.

```yaml
- name: Test
  run: yarn test:ci --verbose --maxWorkers=2
```